# Equivalent form of continum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

The Continuum Hypothesis states that

$$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$$

And Cantor put it equivalently as:

"There is no uncountable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|A| <\mathbb{R}$."

Why are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: Do you see the implication in one of the directions?

Comment: Mario Carneiro's "definition" of $\aleph_1$ isn't quite right.  See my comment below his answer. $\qquad$

Comment: THREE answers now say $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable cardinal or that it's the next cardinal $\text{after }\aleph_0$. Could we recall the definition going back to Cantor, who introduced the notation: $$
\aleph_1 \text{ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals.}
$$ If the axiom of choice holds, then one can show as a corollary of this definition that it's the least uncountable cardinal. But the definition above remains the definition even if one drops the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming you know that $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$, which can be proven by looking at binary expansions of numbers in $[0,1]$ (discounting countably many numbers with non-unique expansions).

The cardinal $\aleph_1$ is by definition the smallest cardinal larger than $\aleph_0$, meaning that there is no set $A$ such that $\aleph_0<|A|<\aleph_1$. Thus in particular, $2^{\aleph_0}\not<\aleph_1$.

In the other direction, if $\aleph_1<2^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|$, then that means that there is an injection $f:\aleph_1\to\Bbb R$, and setting $A$ as the range of $f$, we have $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, and $\aleph_0<|A|=\aleph_1<|\Bbb R|$.

Thus assuming that there are no such sets $A$, we also have $\aleph_1\not<2^{\aleph_0}$, and assuming the axiom of choice this implies $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: While the binary argument is correct, it requires more than the naive approach, because there is a countable set of "mistakes". And one has to argue that a countable set does not matter here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, since it was not the point of the post I didn't want to belabor it, but I rather prefer using *ternary* expansions to avoid this complication, basically proving that the cantor set is a subset of $\Bbb R$ of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ (with a natural bijection).

Comment: While I understand this approach, with time I found it to be confusing. Because the naive approach does not work. It's fine not to delve into the details, but some caveat should be given.

Comment: @Asaf (Caveat given.) It is a bit unfortunate that the binary expansion route is the most prevalent in introductory textbooks, because of this unnecessary complication. I remember reading the Cantor diagonal argument rendered in base 10 using $6$s and $7$s so as to avoid the nonuniqueness problem, but I don't think I've ever seen a direct proof of $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ use this same trick.

Comment: Now I can vote this up with clear conscience!

Comment: The definition of $\aleph_1$, going back to Cantor, is that it is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals.  It is a corollary of the definition that it's the next cardinal after $\aleph_0$, PROVIDED you can't have two incomparable cardinals that are both next after $\aleph_0$.  And if the axiom of choice holds, then they're all comparable. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael You don't need AC to show that there is no set $A$ with $\aleph_0<|A|<\aleph_1$, because $|A|\le\aleph_1$ implies that $A$ is well-orderable, and hence comparable with $\aleph_0$. (This is not an entirely trivial theorem - it uses Cantor's characterization of well-orderable sets as sets equinumerous to an ordinal.)

Comment: @Michael There is a very natural definition of cardinals in which $\aleph_1$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ which does not satisfy $|\alpha|\le\aleph_0$ (which is easily shown equivalent to your definition), and it follows directly from this definition that there are no ordinals $\aleph_0<|\alpha|<\aleph_1$, which can be strengthened to all sets as in the previous comment.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro : I am aware that you don't need AC to show that no cardinal is between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$.  But you do need more than just ZF to rule out incomparability of $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's correct, and is also what I said in my answer. In ZF you can prove both $2^{\aleph_0}\not<\aleph_1$ (unconditionally) and $\aleph_1\not<2^{\aleph_0}$ (under the OP hypothesis), but to conclude $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ you need AC. If this is not the case then $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ are incomparable by definition.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro : In ZF you CANNOT prove that $\aleph_1 \not< 2^{\aleph_0}$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael You apparently missed the (under OP hypothesis) caveat immediately after that. It is a theorem of ZF that if there are no uncountable subsets $A$ of $\Bbb R$ with $|A|<|\Bbb R|$, then $\aleph_1\not<2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the axiom of choice, every two cardinals are comparable. In particular either $\aleph_1\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Since $\aleph_1$ is the *least* uncountable cardinal, and $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable by the diagonal argument, it follows that it is necessarily the case that $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. So the continuum hypothesis is equivalent to saying that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, otherwise there is a set of size $\aleph_1$, pretty much by definition that $\aleph_1<2^{\aleph_0}$, which is intermediate between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$.

Do note, however, that the axiom of choice is essential here. It is possible that the axiom of choice fails, there are not intermediate cardinals between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$, but $\aleph_1\neq2^{\aleph_0}$ (in which case there are incomparable).

Comment: I'd ask what's wrong with the answer that a downvote is in order. But I don't think it has to do with the answer, as much as it has to do with the answerer.

Comment: let's remedy that

Answer (score 2):

$\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable cardinal, and $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. To say that there is no uncountable set with cardinality less than that of $\mathbb{R}$ is precisely to say that $|\mathbb{R}|$ is the least uncountable cardinal; that is, $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers now say $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable cardinal or that it's the next cardinal after $\aleph_0$. Could we recall the definition going back to Cantor, who introduced the notation:

$\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals.

**If the axiom of choice holds,** then one can show that all infinite cardinals are alephs, and those start with $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$, $\aleph_2$, etc., with nothing between alephs with consecutive indices.

Thus if there is nothing between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, then $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, but otherwise $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_1$.